# Add a checkbox dynamically to edittext in android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext, indexoutofboundsexception

I am executing these set of code on a button click. I am trying to add checkboxes dynamically in a edittext. The checkbox is added line by line.

```
    RelativeLayout r1;
    Layout lay = et1.getLayout();
    String text = et1.getText().toString();
    int start=0, end;
            for(int tmp=0; tmp<et1.getLineCount(); tmp++)
                {
                        end = lay.getLineEnd(i);
                        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                        cb.setText(text.substring(start, end));
                        r1.addView(cb);
                        start = end;
                }
```

1)It shows me error as stated below:

```
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 2, 0
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at android.text.PackedIntVector.getValue(PackedIntVector.java:70)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.getLineStart(DynamicLayout.java:375)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at android.text.Layout.getLineEnd(Layout.java:823)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at bitcream.my.notepad.Newnote$7.onClick(Newnote.java:168)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-19 16:05:42.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1965):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

2) Further i want to add these checkboxes to an edittext, probably my code will add it to the relative layout. Kindly suggest me how to fix the error as well as how to add checkbox particularly inside an edittext. Thanks in advance

Comment: IndexOutOfBounds it means that you're trying to get a value from a item that has an index bigger than the last element of the list.
wich one is the line# 168 from Newnote.java ? there is the error

Comment: is your et1 empty when you get this error?

Comment: line number# 168      end lay.getLineEnd(i);

Comment: my edittext is not empty, futher i have not posted the code but i am checking for null value if it is so.. i am using toast to notify it.